# Get all Nav elements and click each nav link

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried too many different ways but really can't get the result I need.

I need to create an automation to test and click all sidebar nav links which are changing contents depending on user to use. So I need to collect and store elements into List and click each but seems not working that way. Tried navigate but will not work as click since it is still on the same URL.

Here's the snippet of code I tried:

```
public void test2() throws InterruptedException {

        driver.get("URL");
        owaLoginPage.loginOwnerAccount("var.EMAIL", var.DEFAULT_PASSWORD);
//        wait.untilElementVisible(owaDashboardPage.getOwnerWebAccountDropdown());
        wait.impWait(50);
        List<WebElement> linksize = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='sidebar-sticky']//a"));
        linksCount = linksize.size();
        System.out.println("Total no of links Available: "+linksCount);
        links= new String[linksCount];
        System.out.println("List of links Available: ");
// print all the links from webpage
        for(int i=0;i<linksCount;i++)
        {
            links[i] = linksize.get(i).getAttribute("href");
            System.out.println(linksize.get(i).getAttribute("href"));
            System.out.println(linksize.get(i).getText());
            driver.navigate().to(links[i]);
            wait.impWait(30);
        }
```

Executing that code returns this:

```
PASSED
Total no of links Available: 7
List of links Available: 
http://url/dashboard.html#
Property1
http://url/dashboard.html#
Unit1-1
http://url/dashboard.html#
Property2
http://url/dashboard.html#
Unit2-1
http://url/dashboard.html#
Unit2-2
http://url/dashboard.html#
Property3
http://url/dashboard.html#
Unit3-1
```

Storing each sidebar elements into separate xpaths is not an option since the objective is to be able to use different user per execution wherein there are different sidebar nav list.

Comment: Just for confirmation your problem is with the clicks? if so have you tried something like this?driver.executeScript("$('#man').click()");

Answer (score 0):

try this

option 1

```
links[i].click();
```

option 2

```
driver.get(links[i]);
```

option 3

```
links[i].SendKeys(string.Empty);
```

option 4

```
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].focus();", links[i]);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nothing worked :( 1 is invalid. 2 has no effect. 3 is invalid. 4 is invalid (No ExecuteScript inside JavaScriptExecutor)